# How to use "Other Than"?

Tags: meaning

"The digital age has given today's libraries new means of storing and retrieving information on media **other than** printed pages."

I looked up the word "other than" on Cambrigde Dictionary. But I still do not understand how to use this word. I feel it means "in addition to", but the dictionary says that it means "except for".

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/other?q=other+than

How should I understand this word correctly?

Many thanks!

Comment: "Other than" occurs only it term comparison. Syntactically, it's probably best analysed as a compound preposition with a meaning like "besides, except, apart from".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the phrase can be replaced with "that are not" and the sentence will still have the same meaning.

> The digital age has given today's libraries new means of storing and retrieving information on media **that are not** printed pages.

"Other than" is for exclusion. Whatever is after the phrase is not in the category. The example lists the new ways libraries can store information. Paper must obviously be excluded from the list because it is not one of these new methods.

Borrowing from BillJ's comment, we could also use "besides" or "apart from"

> The digital age has given today's libraries new means of storing and retrieving information on media **besides** printed pages.
>
> The digital age has given today's libraries new means of storing and retrieving information on media **apart from** printed pages.

"Except" doesn't work for this case.

> The digital age has given today's libraries new means of storing and retrieving information on media **except** printed pages.

"Except" would be used if printed pages was a new storage method that wasn't being taken up by libraries. "Except" can be used as a substitute for "other than" in some situations.

> I am willing to work with anyone here **other than** Rick.
>
> I am willing to work with anyone **except** Rick.