# Does 'those' in 'canonical clauses other than those expressing agent–patient situations' imply 'non-canonical'?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

From [How to use "Other Than"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/203246/how-to-use-other-than)

> The digital age has given today's libraries **new** means of storing and
> retrieving information on media other than **the printed pages**.

'the printed pages' is apparently not 'new means'. So, 'other' in this sentence, in my opinion, may have the meaning of 'otherwise' corresponding to 'new'.

Then, generalizing the analyse from abve to

> **This is a paraphrase:**
>
> Direct object arguments are associated with a wide range of semantic
> roles, but in **canonical** clauses other than ***those*** expressing
> agent–patient situations, the direct object has the same grammatical
> properties as the NP expressing the patient in agent–patient clauses.

The original is

> Direct object arguments are associated with a wide range of semantic
> roles, but in **other canonical clauses than** those expressing
> agent–patient situations, the direct object has the same grammatical
> properties as the NP expressing the patient in agent–patient
> clauses.[Rodney Huddleston Geoffrey K Pullum. (2017). The Cambridge
> Grammar of the English Language. p.245.]

'other' may have the meaning of 'otherwise' corresponding to 'canonical', hence 'non-canonical'.

Comment: Where did you see the first sentence? It seems to contain a typo... please provide a link.

Comment: Where does the "those" in the title of your question come into it? What exactly is your question? And where did the inset quote come from?

Comment: The answer is no. "those expressing agent–patient situations" are also canonical.

Comment: The new (digital) methods of storing information are **different from** the printed page.

Comment: @BillJ Does the paraphrase leave it open that 'those' may be 'non-canonical', whereas the original must be 'canonical' ?

Comment: @Kate Bunting Could I recognize 'other than' or 'other...than...' simply as 'different from...' except the meaning of 'except...' ? I cannot find any specific patterns.

Comment: No: it's the same. Buy I don't see why you are dwelling on the term 'canonical. H&P''s reference here to 'canonical' is to say that the indirect object occurs in canonical clauses only in ditransitives. I don't see the relevance of this to your question.

Comment: And what is the purpose of paraphrasing their wording?

Comment: @BillJ But 'the printed pages' is not 'new means', whereas 'those' is 'canonical'. There may be not any relations, just 'different'.

Comment: "Those" means "canonical clauses", so "other canonical clauses than those expressing agent–patient situations" means "other canonical clauses than canonical clauses expressing agent-patient situation".

Comment: @BillJ 'new means' is in the first sentence,and 'the printed pages' is not a kind of 'new means'. But in the paraphrase 'those' is a kind of 'canonical clauses'. So I cannot understand this kind of usage of 'other than', because it looks like a little competing.

Comment: I just gave you the meaning! Your paraphrase and H&P's wording mean the same. "canonical clauses other than those ..." means the same as "other canonical clauses than those ..."

Comment: @BillJ,Thank you. "more than" is a little hard to master.